# Are there only activities with a UI on the stack / task

Tags: android

I've been going over the documentation in detail, but found no answer.

Do I understand correct that there are only activities with a UI on the stack / task?
Meaning that there are never BaseActivities on the stack in a task.

Answer (score 0):

if u **visit** that activity , that will be in stack,i don't think parent activity class i.e baseactivity will be saved in stack.